# Dynamically select data from a table name that is stored in a another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, dynamic-tables

I'm new to SQL Server (version 15) and I need help writing the SQL.

I have an Invoice_Header table that has Invoice_ID and Invoice_Dt as keys:

| Invoice_ID | Invoice_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 |
| 2 | 1/1/2021 |
| 3 | 2/1/2021 |
| 4 | 3/1/2021 |

There is an Invoice_Detail table with Invoice_ID, Invoice_Dt, Invoice_Line as keys and ID & Table_Name fields.

| Invoice_ID | Invoice_Date | Invoice_Line | ID | Table_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 | 1 | 2 | Food_Table |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 | 2 | 1 | Drink_Table |
| 2 | 1/1/2021 | 1 | 1 | Food_Table |
| 2 | 1/1/2021 | 2 | 3 | Drink_Table |
| 3 | 2/1/2021 | 1 | 3 | Food_Table |
| 4 | 3/1/2021 | 1 | 2 | Drink_Table |

Food_Table has these 2 fields

| ID | Food_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Hamburger |
| 2 | Hot Dog |
| 3 | Pasta |

Drink_Table has these 2 fields

| ID | Drink_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Soda |
| 2 | Milk |
| 3 | Water |

I want to pull data with these columns:

| Invoice | Invoice_Dt | Invoice_Line | Order_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 | 1 | Hot Dog |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 | 2 | Soda |
| 2 | 1/1/2021 | 1 | Hamburger |
| 2 | 1/1/2021 | 2 | Water |
| 3 | 2/1/2021 | 1 | Pasta |
| 4 | 3/1/2021 | 1 | Milk |

Thus, for each invoice line on the Invoice_Detail table, it has the ID and table_name to either the Food_Table or Drink_Table. Whatever the ID is on these two respective tables, I need to get the Food_Name or Drink_Name as the Order_Name. Note that the example contains only these two tables. However, it could have multiple tables. So the SQL would need to go to the table_name that is on the invoice_detail table. Therefore, cannot do hardcoding Food_Table and Drink_Table.

I do not know how to write such a SQL and would really appreciate it if someone could show me how to write one.

Thanks

Comment: Have you made any attempts? If not, why have you researched to try and solve the problem? Is fixing the design possible? As someone who is new to SQL this design is a very bad choice. Creating a database that mandates dynamic SQL is a design flaw even for those very well versed in the language, or both SQL *and* dynamic SQL.

Comment: The design of the database is your issue here. You shouldn't have separate tables "Food" and "Drink". Instead, you should have one table for all invoiceable items. If you need to categorize the individual items, add an "item type" field, which would contain the values "Food" and "Drink".

Comment: Depending on how extensive your build is going down this path, you could still avoid dynamic sql pretty easily. You could write a single query using conditional joins to each table and only actually perform the joins to the table that matches the value of `Invoice_Detail.Table_Name`. Or you could do something like create a stored procedure and use flow statements like `IF Table_Name = 'Food_Table' BEGIN SELECT YourColumns FROM YourTables LEFT JOIN Food_Table ON YourConditions; END;` to conditionally run the appropriate query.

Comment: @Larnu. I did not create the database. I'm just a user trying to retrieve data for reporting purpose.

Comment: Fixing the design is the right choice here then, but I doubt (with respect) you are neither in a position to do that, not have the knowledge. As such we need to know the answer to @trenton-ftw 's implied question. Can the column `Table_Name` have any other values than the 2 in your question?

Comment: @trenton-ftw. The issue is that the table_name value on the Invoice_Detail can be anything and not fixed. I'm only giving 2 tables (Food & Drink) as examples. But there could be more and I don't want to hardcode and do it for each table_name. Furthermore, as I understand it, there could be new values under the table_name so if there are new table_names, then I would need to modify the procedure add it to the statement.

Comment: @Larnu, yes there could be more values in the table_name. Furthermore, there could be new values as well.

Comment: @user3241884 ah sorry about that. Just figured I'd make the suggestion in case there were only a few. You could still avoid dynamic sql by creating a warehouse type table that is a concatenation of tables like `Drink_Table` and `Food_Table` with an added value of `Table_Name` as a field. Then you can join to this warehoused table with `Invoice_Detail.Table_Name = NewTable.Table_Name AND Invoice_Detail.ID = NewTable.ID`. This is of course dependent a bit on your schema and if you are able to standardize fields from your tables like `Food_Table` and `Drink_Table`.

Comment: I really would suggest talking to the designers about fixing the design then, if I am honest, @user3241884 . Otherwise, you are going to have to go down the dynamic SQL approach, it's unlikely to be performant, and unless you truly know what you are doing, you are going to be introducing a wealth of security vulnerabilities into your system.

Comment: I understand that this is not an ideal data design. However, it's a third party app and thereby it's not possible for me to ask the designers to change. It is what it is. I'm asking for help to write a sql (dynamic or any)  to get the data I need for reporting without me doing a manual excel data manipulation by looking at the tables on the invoice_detail and do a vlookup.

Comment: With table names in columns you need dynamic SQL. Dynamic SQL merely means that you select (meta) data and use this to build your final select. Some DBMS offer this feature somehow, but it can just as well be done with any app / programing language. The problem here, however, is that not only the table names, but also the column names differ. Is it guaranteed that the column names match the table names (**food**_table -> **food**_name)? If not, you'll have to select from system tables and make sophisticated guesses.

Comment: In Oracle or PostgreSQL the best approach here would probably be to add a name column to the invoice_datails table and then fill this column with a trigger which itself uses dynamic SQL. I don't think, however, this is possible in SQL Server. I may be wrong, though.

Answer (score 1):

If there are just a few tables, I wouldn't try to do anything "clever" with dynamic SQL or get too fancy. The easiest way to do it is to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to the tables and include the value of `Table_Name` in the join condition, then use the `COALESCE` function to return the first non-null value (and there should only be one anyway).

The query is simply this:

```
SELECT i.Invoice_ID AS [Invoice], i.Invoice_Date AS [Invoice_Dt], 
i.Invoice_Line, COALESCE(d.Drink_Name, f.Food_Name) AS [Order_Name]
FROM Invoice_Detail AS i
LEFT OUTER JOIN Drink_Table d ON d.ID = i.ID AND i.Table_Name ='Drink_Table'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Food_Table f ON f.ID = i.ID AND i.Table_Name = 'Food_Table'
```

If you want to try this out, I created a simple script that declares table variables and populates them with your sample data. You can run the script or modify it to try out different results. If you have more tables, you just need more `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s... that is likely the easiest way to handle this situation.

```
DECLARE @Invoice_Header AS TABLE (
    [Invoice_ID] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Invoice_Date] DATE NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @Invoice_Header(Invoice_ID,Invoice_Date)
VALUES (1, '1/1/2021'),(2, '1/1/2021'),(3,'2/1/2021'),(4,'3/1/2021');

DECLARE @Invoice_Detail AS TABLE (
    [Invoice_ID] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Invoice_Date] DATE NOT NULL, 
    [Invoice_Line] INT NOT NULL, 
    [ID] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Table_Name] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @Invoice_Detail(Invoice_ID,Invoice_Date,Invoice_Line,ID,Table_Name)
VALUES (1, '1/1/2021',1,2,'Food_Table'),(1,'1/1/2021',2,1,'Drink_Table'),
(2,'1/1/2021',1,1,'Food_Table'),(2,'1/1/2021',2,3,'Drink_Table'), 
(3,'2/1/2021',1,3,'Food_Table'),(4,'3/1/2021',1,2,'Drink_Table');

DECLARE @Food_Table AS TABLE(
    [ID] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Food_Name] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @Food_Table(ID,Food_Name)
VALUES (1,'Hamburger'),(2,'Hot Dog'),(3,'Pasta');

DECLARE @Drink_Table AS TABLE(
    [ID] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Drink_Name] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @Drink_Table(ID,Drink_Name)
VALUES (1,'Soda'),(2,'Milk'),(3,'Water');

SELECT i.Invoice_ID AS [Invoice], i.Invoice_Date AS [Invoice_Dt], 
i.Invoice_Line, COALESCE(d.Drink_Name, f.Food_Name) AS [Order_Name]
FROM @Invoice_Detail AS i
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Drink_Table d ON d.ID = i.ID AND i.Table_Name ='Drink_Table'
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Food_Table f ON f.ID = i.ID AND i.Table_Name = 'Food_Table'
```

You will see the expected output:

| Invoice | Invoice_Dt | Invoice_Line | OrderName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 1 | Hot Dog |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2 | Soda |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 1 | Hamburger |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2 | Water |
| 3 | 2021-02-01 | 1 | Pasta |
| 4 | 2021-03-01 | 1 | Milk |

Comment: Thanks. I only gave two tables as an example to simplify. The system that I'm using (which is from a third party) actually has 37 tables and can grow. I know and agree with everyone that the design is bad. With two tables, I can certainly do the select sql or a stored procedure as shown or using cte.  But all of these require hardcoding/selecting the tables. And if new tables are added, then have to modify. I guess there is not a way to do it without hardcoding or without resorting to writing codes.

Comment: Since in your example the name of the column that you want to display is different in the other tables, there is no great way to do it that is automatic. I agree, the design is awful but I also know that when you have a 3rd party system you don't get to tell them to fix their issues... I just wanted to provide an answer instead of some snarky comment about the design when you had a legitimate question.  Honestly, even with 37 tables the query isn't that bad, but given that it can grow you will have to be ready to maintain the query.